# Drag fill skips row Index

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help in Excel. I have a catalog that has data arranged horizontally. I need to make a mobile version of it that has same value but in vertical boxes. when I do a drag fill,   [link to example](https://file.io/4mIT13zvaFaY)

on each vertical drag it jumps with as many rows as I have selected. I want it to add +1. I am uploading a similar logic file. It would be great if someone could help me  tanks.

Comment: The link is dead, but it sounds like you want something like: `=Index(range,,row(A1))` dragged down

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.